# Laravel Folder Structure - Nested PHP Files in Views Folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I have multiple nested PHP files that relate to a view, where should I put them? In the `app` folder, `resources\views` folder, `resources\assets` folder?

---

**resources\views** folder structure:

[image]

---

**lemon.blade.php**  contents:

```
@include('lemon.top.top')
@include('lemon.bottom.bottom')
```

If these subfiles aren't included in the `resources\views` folder, how do I reference them in lemon.blade.php?

Comment: this looks correct - saving within `resources/views` -- what's not working?

Comment: This works, but should I include MULTIPLE nested php files in the views folder, or should they be included elsewhere?

Comment: that's the spot for view files - nest it as deep as you need

Answer (score 2):

They are to be created within `resources\views`.

If you are looking for best practices, you can create a `partials` folder within `views`, where you can even organize with more folders.

One suggestion made by **Jeffrey Way** from **Laracasts**, is to name all partials with a preceding `_`, so it's clearly differentiated from `views`.

Answer (score 0):

**resources\assets** is the space to include all your js, css, etc, resources in general

If your resources are related to an specific view, you could create a similar folder structure inside your assets folder